# Invalid filename or mode 'wb'

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I am using django. I was trying to compress an icon uploaded by a user to a smaller size using Pythons Image library.

Following is my code:

```
def resizeImage(icon,ext):
     path= os.path.join(settings.SITE_ROOT,'karnadash/static/tempfiles/temp'+ext)
     destination = open(path,'wb+')
     for chunk in icon.chunks():
         destination.write(chunk)
     destination.close()
     image = Image.open(path)
     image= image.resize((50, 50), Image.ANTIALIAS)
     image.save(path)
     return image
```

Problem is I am getting an internal server error. The last part of the stack trace is as follows:

```
 line 31, in resizeImage
     image.save(path)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1446, in save
     fp = builtins.open(fp, "wb+")
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: 'C:/Users/Silent/Documents/Python/karnadash/karnadash/static/tempfiles/temp.jpg'
```

Can anybody please explain why this is happening?

Comment: Is there really a newline in the `IOError` message? Please do not reformat such lines.

Comment: Nope I copied it from command prompt so maybe that is why.

Comment: Right, Windows cmd is terrible for copy and pasting indeed.

Comment: People will see the question, regardless.

Comment: Voting to close as not reproducible. The provided information doesn't let us see what was actually wrong with the filename here, and there are much better questions for general problems with filenames on Windows, such as [Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python).

Answer (score 2):

What solved it for me was switching from backslashes to forward slashes! Who would've thought?!

Similar post: [ioerror invalid mode w](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141761/region-ioerror-errno-22-invalid-mode-w-or-filename)

Comment: This is clearly not related to the question OP is asking about, since the path shown here uses forward slashes. The problem with using backslashes is *extremely* well covered by other, better questions.

Answer (score 1):

Check your file path if it's valid:

```
C:/Users/Silent/Documents/Python/karnadash/karnadash/static/tempfiles/temp.jpg
```

Perhaps it contains one `karnadash` too much.

Comment: That won't change anything.
I have tried a similar thing from the python IDLE and it worked fine.
And Django does not allow backslahes in absolute paths.

Comment: No its fine. Actually the error is very inconsistent should I post a complete edit I have discovered some new things.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem when I was trying to save some figures in a fowder. Some figures I could save, but couldn't save others, and I was using the same code. I realized that the name of the figure and the backslash were in conflict with a reserved code.

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: '02102016\nDTG.png'
```

I think `"\n"` was interpreted as "enter". The problem had been solved when I changed it to forward slash.

Comment: There is no `/n` in the filename of the question